# Remove non numeric rows from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance

I have a dataframe of patients and their gene expressions. I has this format:

```
Patient_ID | gene1 | gene2 | ... | gene10000
    p1       0.142   0.233   ...      bla
    p2       0.243   0.243   ...    -0.364
    ...
    p4000    1.423    bla    ...    -1.222
```

As you see, that dataframe contains noise, with cells that are values other then a float value.

I want to remove every row that has a any column with non numeric values.

I've managed to do this using `apply` and `pd.to_numeric` like this:

```
cols = df.columns[1:]
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
df = df.dropna()
```

The problem is that it's taking for ever to run, and I need a better and more efficient way of achieving this

**EDIT**: To reproduce something like my data:

```
arr = np.random.random_sample((3000,10000))
df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=['gene' + str(i) for i in range(10000)])
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(['p' + str(i) for i in range(10000)], columns=['Patient_ID']),df],axis = 1)
df['gene0'][2] = 'bla'
df['gene9998'][4] = 'bla'
```

Comment: That's as efficient as it can get. Your data must be big?

Comment: Yes, that's my data unfortunately..

Comment: Could you provide minimal reproducible example? I think it worth to try do that in numpy

Comment: @dankal444 I've added something. Row `2` and `4` should be discarded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was right it is worth trying numpy :)

I got 30-60x times faster version (bigger array, larger improvement)

1. Convert to numpy array (`.values`)
2. Iterate through all rows
3. Try to convert each row to row of floats
4. If it fails (some NaN present), note this in boolean array
5. Create array based on the results

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from line_profiler_pycharm import profile


def op_version(df):
    cols = df.columns[1:]
    df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
    return df.dropna()


def np_version(df):
    keep = np.full(len(df), True)
    for idx, row in enumerate(df.values[:, 1:]):
        try:
            row.astype(np.float)
        except:
            keep[idx] = False
            pass    # maybe its better to store to_remove list, depends on data
    return df[keep]


@profile
def main():
    arr = np.random.random_sample((3000, 5000))
    df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=['gene' + str(i) for i in range(5000)])
    df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(['p' + str(i) for i in range(3000)],
                                 columns=['Patient_ID']), df], axis=1)
    df['gene0'][2] = 'bla'
    df['gene998'][4] = 'bla'
    df2 = df.copy()

    df = op_version(df)
    df2 = np_version(df2)
```

Note I decreased number of columns so it is more feasible for tests.

Also, fixed small bug in your example, instead of:
`df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(['p' + str(i) for i in range(10000)], columns=['Patient_ID']),df],axis = 1)`
I think should be
`df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(['p' + str(i) for i in range(3000)], columns=['Patient_ID']),df],axis = 1)`

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I’ll test it tomorrow. Regarding the reproducible example, it was only for the example. The data comes from a csv

Comment: Note that it may be faster to operate column by column as iterating over rows is generally quite slow, especially with a lot of columns.

Comment: @JérômeRichard in general yes, more cache friendly. But it would have to be some different approach than mine. Using ValueError to detect NaN in a row won't work in column by column algorithm

Comment: And BTW I found it strange that there is no argument in numpy astype that allows to write NaNs where ValueError are raised during conversion. It would make column by column algorithm fairly easy.

Comment: @dankal444 Regarding astype, Numpy use a unique conversion method for all methods in Numpy requiring such a thing. This conversion method is relatively fast because it is based on a low-level C conversion. Adding checks would make the conversion more user-friendly (and prevent some undefined behaviour) at the expense of a significantly slower conversion. Ideally, this conversion can be then optimized using SIMD instructions manually but this is a significant work (and maintenance effort) because of the many different supported types so we choose not to do that so far.

Comment: @dankal444 If such safer function would be implemented, then raising Python exception based on it would be relatively simple I guess. For now, we just wanted to warn user about bad conversions without (significantly) impacting performance.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Honestly, still do not get it. From my perspective: There must be some checks in the conversion (string->float in this case) that cause ValueError to be raised. Why not just "catch" such an error, write NaN as a result of conversion and go on with conversion? It seems it should not impact performance at all.